# Storing table at different memory address - C for AVR XMEGA256A3BU

Tags: c, assembly, avr

I'm trying to figure out how to store the fahrenheit table to memory address 0x20 instead of the default 0x0000. I have tried several routes, but so far, nothing that works. The code is in C.

```
#include <avr/io.h> 
#include <avr/eeprom.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
    uint8_t fahrenheit[20] =
         {32,34,36,37,39,41,43,45,46,48,50,52,54,55,57,59,61,63,64,66}; 

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
   {  
       eeprom_write_byte((uint8_t *)i, fahrenheit[i]); 
   }         
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding an offset?

Comment: I am a student that is new to this. Will you please ellaborate?

Comment: I'm surprised there is a "default" address, considering `fahrenheit` is an object with automatic storage duration.

Comment: By the way, who write this library `uint8_t` is not a byte, it's an octet.

Comment: @EOF: In SRAM and flash, sure. But not in EEPROM.

Comment: @EOF It looks like he's trying to write data to EEPROM- special read-only memory. The address of a local object in RAM as it exists on the stack obeys the usual rules.

Comment: @Stargateur Your code is writing to decimal location 20, not hex location 0x20 (which corresponds to decimal location 32).

Comment: I did see that the decimal location is 32. So far, the only thing that seems to get me in the right direction is another for loop where my counter goes from 20 to 39 (decimal locations).

Comment: There are methods for interpreting a given address as a pointer to a variable, which allows storing whatever you like there. But I think what you are asking for is a method to **link** a certain variable at a certain address. For doing that, you'd have to study the options of influencing your linker. Defining a special RAM section and selecting it (e.g. by using a corresponding `#pragma`understodd by your compiler) right before the definition of the variable is the method I know for doing that.

Comment: By the way, taking the [tour] means good luck, I recommend it.

Comment: I found some possible solutions that should do this without "cheating." However, I don't get the results I'm looking for.

Comment: The XMEGA256A3BU has a hardware multiplier so it would probably be more efficient to do the conversion arithmetically rather than using a table lookup in EEPROM memory.

Comment: The main question would be: Why would you want to store a °F-to-°C-table in EEPROM? Are you expecting to change it anytime soon? The other thing is: If you do it like that, you'll end up with two (or, rather, three) copies of the data: Once in Flash, the other in EEPROM, the last one temporarily in RAM.

Comment: After working on this some more, it seems that the goal was to really understand how and where data uses memory. By the end of it all, I pulled the data from EEPROM, converted it, and saved the Celsius data to SRAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eeprom_write_byte((uint8_t *)i, fahrenheit[i]);` writes a value to address `i`. Therefore, to write value starting from 0x0020 as you wish, just do this `eeprom_write_byte((uint8_t *)i+20, fahrenheit[i]);`

Comment: This is a perfect solution for what I'm doing.

Comment: It is so simple. I think I was overthinking it.